# Everything is glitchy (objects are invisible and/or glitched)

Tags: 3d-view, gpu

I am having this weird problem since almost two weeks. I don't know how to explain it, but objects have become invisible (even though i'm in solid mode and xray is off), like this

[image: What happens when I open Blender]

Also, if I add another object, the whole scene becames totally glitched out

[image: What happens after adding another object]

In this case I just added a circle to the scene.

I think that this have to do with my graphics drivers, but I already tried to reinstall them, fixing the issue for like 1 day, then the next day I'm again with this glitchy viewport.
I have an old APU A10-5750m with Radeon 8650g, and I know it's not the best to work with.

Anyone had a similar issue? How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Hello :). Your GPU is able to *run* Blender ([it's supported](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)), but it's probably not good enough to actually use it. Switching to an [older Blender version](https://download.blender.org/release/) could help. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Jachym. I partially fixed for now reinstalling the gpu drivers. If the issue comes back again, I will have no choice but go back to the latest working version 2.81, which I used a lot on the same laptop without this issue.